# how to calculate network address of an IP with subnet mask 202.145.90.7/20?

Tags: networking, ip, hosts, subnet

how to calculate  network  address of an IP with subnet mask 202.145.90.7/20? How many hosts can be there?

Comment: How about doing your homework yourself? ;)

Comment: @DanielB hehe yes but i don't have any interest in networking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be 4094 hosts. There are many online subnet calculators, e.g., [IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc), [Subnet mask calculator](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SubnetCalculator.jsp), and [ip subnet calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/), which you can use to answer such questions. A /20 subnet is equivalent to a subnet mask of 255.255.240.0

[Results from IP Calcuator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=202.145.90.7%2F&mask1=20&mask2=):

```
Address:   202.145.90.7          11001010.10010001.0101 1010.00000111
Netmask:   255.255.240.0 = 20    11111111.11111111.1111 0000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.15.255            00000000.00000000.0000 1111.11111111
=>
Network:   202.145.80.0/20       11001010.10010001.0101 0000.00000000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 202.145.95.255        11001010.10010001.0101 1111.11111111
HostMin:   202.145.80.1          11001010.10010001.0101 0000.00000001
HostMax:   202.145.95.254        11001010.10010001.0101 1111.11111110
Hosts/Net: 4094
```

If you wish to know how to perform subnet calculations yourself, Udemy offers a free course titled 
[*IP Addressing and Subnetting*](http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=kd/Y23PG*g0&subid=&offerid=323058.1&type=10&tmpid=14537&RD_PARM1=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Fip-adressing-and-subnetting%2F%3Fdtcode%3DHrMhqQN2dZmk)

Answer (score 1):

Calculate it on [subnet calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=B)
But it would be great to read [Andrwe Tanenbaums - Computer Networks](http://cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~minhnguyen/NET/Computer%20Networks%20-%20A%20Tanenbaum%20-%205th%20edition.pdf), whole would be great, but for this question 5.6.2 chapter will probably do the trick. *I dont want to copy/paste his entire page.*